# PHP calculator with words as operators

Tags: php, jquery, class

I am stuck in resolving a PHP script.

I want to calculate a result from a set of instructions. Instructions comprise of a keyword and a number that are separated by a space per line. Instructions are loaded from file and results are output to the screen. Any number of Instructions can be specified. Instructions are operators (add, divide, subtract, multiply). The instructions will ignore mathematical precedence. The last instruction should be “apply” and a number (e.g., “apply 3”). The calculator is then initialised with that number and the previous instructions are applied to that number.

```
[Input]
add 2
multiply 3
apply 3
[Output]
15
```

[Explanation]
(3 + 2) * 3 = 15

example

```
[Input]
multiply 9
apply 5
[Output]
45
```

Can anyone help with some example logic or code ?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
class calculator {

    public
    function calculate($expression) {
        $expression = str_replace(' ', '', $expression);
        return $this - > exec($expression);
    }
    private
    function exec($expression) {

        switch ($expression['op']) {
            case 'add':
                $r = $expression[0] + $expression[1];
                break;
            case 'subtract':
                $r = $expression[0] - $expression[1];
                break;
            case 'multiply':
                $r = $expression[0] * $expression[1];
                break;
            case 'divide':
                $r = $expression[0] / $expression[1];
                break;

        }
        return $r;
    }

    private
    function parseExpression($expression) {

        $blankspace = preg_match('/\s/', $expression);

        $counter = count($expression);
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically it's left to right, except stick the "apply X" in front? And what's the range of input?

Comment: raekye thanks for your time, the input is textarea each instruction is in a line, next one mustbe in a new line ( ex : multiply 5 then new line add 6 then new line apply3) how can i implement this

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like you are just asking someone to code it for you.

Comment: i have updated the code with what i have tried so far, but i can et right the logic

Comment: thanks samuel for the jquer solution

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way:

```
class Calculator {
    public $result = 0;
    public $queue = Array();
    public parseString($text) {
       // parse input string
       $cmds = explode(" ", $text);
       foreach($cmds as $cmd) {
          $cmd = trim($cmd);
          if(!$cmd) continue; // blank or space, ignoring
          $this->queue[] = $cmd;
       }

       // lets process commands
       $command = false;
       foreach($this->queue as $index => $cmd) { 
           if(is_number($cmd)) {
               // if it's number fire previous command if exists
               if(!$command || !method_exists($this, $command)) {
                   throw new Exception("Unknown command $command");
               }
               $this->$command($index, $cmd);
           }else{
               $command = $cmd;
           }
       }
    }
    public function apply($index, $number) {
       // manipulate $result, $queue, $number
    }
    public function add($index, $number) {
       // manipulate $result, $queue, $number
    }
    public function substract($index, $number) {
       // manipulate $result, $queue, $number
    }
}

$calculator = new Calculator();
$calculator->parseString('...');
```

It's just example how you can do it, but it's your job to do it :)

You gonna need to add some methods like `clearQueue`, `clearResult`, `setResult` etc...

Comment: thanks peter, how can i trigger the apply or divide method ? i am a beginner in php

Comment: before `// lets process commands` you should sort $queue by custom precedence, and `apply` should be first. method apply should looks like this: `function apply($index, $number) { $this->result = $number; }`

Comment: there is no math precedence asked, i m having a clearer idea about the logic, but how can i call or switch the add,divide,multiply,substract and how to distinguish and trigger apply word, can you give more help plz